# Fast way to merge to master

Tags: git

I have a stable master branch, and a "messing around" dev branch.

When the dev branch is OK and ready for release, I do:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push
git checkout dev
```

I'm wondering if there's not some easier way to do it?
I know I could make alias to this, but maybe there's something like `git release` which I am missing?

Comment: This kind of thing is what scripts are for. Hell, make it a oneliner with a comment and just ^R for it.

Comment: I'm presuming you are merging `master` into `dev` before merging `dev` into `master`? You should be, or the `push` may not work.

Comment: Yeah I should, but it's a one-man repo and there's never anything changed in master. Good to keep that in mind tho

Answer (score 2):

This does only work if your merge is fast-forward, i.e. there were no commits on `master` since you created the `dev` branch:

```
git fetch . dev:master
```

You can also replace the `.` with a remote repository.

Note that this command will not create a merge commit. It will just forward your `master` to the top of your `dev` branch.

Comment: When I run this, should I be in dev or master?

Comment: It doesn't matter. So you can stay on the dev branch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make the four commands you have above shorter, save to script them, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push
git checkout dev
```

Note the use of `set -e` to stop on an error, and `set -x` to print out what it's doing.

As @StefanFerstl pointed out, if you know the case is simpler, you can use fewer commands. But not for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers that outline scripted solutions, you might want to take a look at "Git Flow": http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

It provides tools and a process for things like feature branches, releases, hot fixes, etc.

Your example above could be done with something like

```
git flow release start 1.0.0
```

And then followed by

```
git flow release finish 1.0.0
```

Comment: This is awesome, I'm definitely bookmarking it. Thanks!